# c++ maps value get corrupted

Tags: c++, linux, dictionary

I created one multimap `ErrorMap` and inserting values like this

```
map<char*,char*> ErrorMap;
ErrorMap.insert(map<char*, char*>::value_type(*l_itrList, ErrorMsg1));
```

After this I am reading this map three times for processing some requests. before deleting I print map and I am getting first two pair values corrupted, and rest values are OK.

I am getting core dump here.

Can I get the details how those values affected while reading. Any solution so that I can save my map till I explicitly delete it.

my logs

> mapItrMov4.first (€J+) mapItrMov4.second (Invalid Service Request)
>
> mapItrMov4.first (hK+) mapItrMov4.second (Invalid Service Request)
>
> mapItrMov4.first (first) mapItrMov4.second (InvalidServiceRequest)

....

and it is fine after that

gdb backtrace

(gdb) bt

0x001c2cae in raise () from /lib/tls/i686/libc.so.6

0x001c42b0 in abort () from /lib/tls/i686/libc.so.6

0x001f2469 in __libc_message () from /lib/tls/i686/libc.so.6

0x001f7ef8 in _int_free () from /lib/tls/i686/libc.so.6

0x001f824f in free () from /lib/tls/i686/libc.so.6

0x004dbfd1 in operator delete () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6

0x004dc01d in operator delete[] () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6

0x080ab607 in amsAccMgmtReqHandler::opServicesReqHandler (this=0x95b91dc,
        m_Response=0x95ba588 "68287

0x080b35c4 in amsAccMgmtReqHandler::handleRequest (this=0x95b91dc,
        a_cpRequestStr=0x2187820 "1<
    MSISDN>102000073589953099999000000000599999000"...,
        a_cpResponseStr=0x95ba588 "68287

0x081344d5 in amsWorker::run (this=0x95b91d0)

0x081cef83 in workerThread::ThreadProc (p=0x959f234)

0x003ca144 in start_thread () from /lib/tls/i686/libpthread.so.0

0x00258a7e in clone () from /lib/tls/i686/libc.so.6

Comment: Guess: the lifetime of either `**l_itrList` or `*ErrorMsg1` ends while the map still exists (e.g. they are local variables and go out of scope). Can you post more on what these are?

Comment: Did you use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to find memory leaks?

Comment: @Angew... That is around 900 LOC. So posting more code  is not possible. And even I am not having any idea where those values are affecting. So I don`t know which part I need to post here.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch... I use `GDB` I think it is good to use gdb itself.

Comment: @Angew... Except first two values everything is fine so I don`t think that it is local variable issue. Is it????

Comment: But `gdb` and `valgrind` are complementary. You should use both, so really try `valgrind` (which is really simple to use). Also, compile with `g++ -Wall -g` (and maybe try also `-Wextra` and perhaps  [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) ....)

Comment: Can you at least show the full *type* of `ErrorMap` ? As in, the declaration of it, and if its type is a typedef, that as well ? And now that I see you just posted the stack trace, this map is being hit from multiple threads, so is it protected via mutex during access ops?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I can all-but-guarantee you that map is *not* doing what you think it is, and very likely is non-conforming to the standard for address comparison since it is using the default `std::less<>` comparator on raw pointers that in-all-likelihood are not from the same allocated contiguous memory region. Use a `std::map<std::string,std::string>` instead. Without a custom-comparator and an engineer wielding a well-thought-out plan, raw pointers make *lousy* map keys, and are usually the wrong idea.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that because your map's type is `<char*, char*>`,so when you read it, the content where pointer **points** have been **deleted** and made pointer become **wild pointer**.

When map do **insert**, it simply **copy it's value**. which means: if type is pointer, it **copy pointer's value** but **not** the content it points.

Why not change type to `<string, string>`? std::string handles copy at very low costs and avoid the problem caused by pointer.

Comment: I think you didn`t read my question. I said only first two values... after that I am getting 10 values correctly... Please first read my question.

Comment: Things may still work if you use `map<char*, char*>` depending on how memory is managed, so just because it works occasionally, doesn't mean it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

So I'm going to assume the type of `ErrorMap` is `map<char*, char*>`, because you take that type's `value_type` for inserting.

The moment you write `map<char*` you've already lost. You get memory management issues, and in addition you don't get correct sorting, because it will sort by pointer value instead of string value. And it's not const-safe, because it doesn't stop you from modifying what the keys point to, which is another wonderful way of corrupting a map.

Just use a `map<string, string>` and get rid of a mountain of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is I am using `iterator` when providing values to `map key`. And after sometime I am extracted values from this `iterator`. When I got values I am deleting some values from map(unknowingly) and that is my problem. After continuously printing logs I got my answer.